# How to shutdown specific camel route at runtime?

Tags: apache-camel

How to shutdown specific camel route at runtime?

In our application we have multiple camel routes and I want to shutdown specific one during runtime when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the API on `CamelContext` that has methods to stop route(s).
http://camel.apache.org/lifecycle

You can do this via Java API or JMX API etc.

Also you can use the controlbus component to stop routes also
http://camel.apache.org/controlbus

And if you use Spring Boot then it has actuator endpoints where you can turn on, to allow to control routes and then you can do a HTTP call to those actuator to control the routes.

And if you use Apache Karaf then there is a set of Camel commands that allows you to manage your Camel applications from the Karaf shell, where you can also stop routes etc.

Comment: Thanks @Claus Ibsen i tried using actuator endpoints and it worked.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in distributed environment? do i need to hit endpoint on each server?

Comment: Yes you would need to do that

Comment: Hey, has this change in version 3.3 of camel? I am unable to find anything looking like "stop" or "shutdown" offered by the context.

Comment: use camelcontext.getRouteController() that can control routes - see the upgrade guide: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3x-upgrade-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```
exchange.getContext().stopRoute(idOfYourRoute);
exchange.getContext().removeRoute(idOfYourRoute);
```